# JavaFX: Two or more Panes at same Position

Tags: javafx

I have two Panes with populated nodes.
when I layout the panes side by side I can act on them and all works fine.
what I now want to do is, that I stack them at the same position, so that only one pane is visible. Similar nodes with the statement: node.toFront();

Is that possible?

M

Comment: Yes? `Pane`s are `Node`s after all. Where is the problem?

Comment: If you have two `Pane` nodes side-by-side, then you have them inside of a single parent. What type of node is the parent? Is it an `HBox`?

Comment: no that is a StackPane

Answer (score 2):

Definitively is possible, you just need to use a StackPane, this component has the required behaviour by default. However, I would recommend you remove the first node before to add another one, just for performance reasons.

Comment: I think I do not need a StackPane thats not the problem.

Comment: I have 2 populated ancherPanes side by side that works great. But I want both at the same position in a container and I don´t how to do that. There is no code pane.toFront();

Comment: Perhaps you do need a StackPane Mike and that is the problem.  If you tried it and it still doesn't work, perhaps edit your question and include [code for your failed attempt](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: when I use a StackPane I do not know how to populate Buttons, Labels and other. They all stacked thats not what I want, but I think I found it!!! here it is: anchorPane1.setVisible(true); anchorPane2.setVisible(false); or anchorPane1.setVisible(false); anchorPane2.setVisible(true); That works.

Comment: You could use you AnchorPane and inside of it a StackPane to overlap the nodes, could you provide a code fragment for review it and help you

Comment: Thx, but it works I was looking for .setVisible instead .toFront